# enable IntelliSense for single .cs file in Vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am currently compiling my C# code using a batch file which calls the mono compiler "mcs"

I'd like to use Visual Studio to edit my .cs file

IntelliSense, however, neither auto suggest members for namespaces such as System and System.Windows.Forms nor the members properties

Is there any way to reference the libraries to IntelliSense so that I get the auto suggestions, but without making a project / using the VS compiler?

Comment: If you create solution, project, and source (.cs) files entirely in Visual Studio, does intellisense work? N.B. Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/) might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Yep it works fine like that, but I wanted to somehow reference the libraries soley to IntelliSense if that is possible. Also why is this question downvoted does Visual Studio related questions not belong on Super User?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the behavior that you describe. Without digging into it, I can only speculate that there's something in the project (.csproj) that's triggering recognition by VS and thereby enabling intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio needs the project system to track which version of the .NET Framework you're targeting and which DLLs you have referenced.  There is no way outside the project structure to do this.

You could look into the lighter project structure (xproj) used by [ASP.NET 5](http://www.asp.net/vnext).  Another alternative would be [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which doesn't required a project system.